# In collection form foreign key always null

Tags: symfony, associations, many-to-one, formcollection

I hope I can be clear in my question.
In my symfony2 project I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKyoJZqxxUU) tutorial to make a form in which I can press the link to add as many "auteur" as the user wants, so I tried to do it with form collection.
Everything works fine, except the many to one field that always gets "null" value and not the "id".
Here is what I have done.

Soumission entity in which I have the add "auteur" link

```
....
  /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Auteur", 
  mappedBy="soumission", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $auteurs;
.....
/**
 * @param Collection $auteurs
 * @return $this
 */

public function setAuteurs(Collection $auteurs)
{
    $this->auteurs = $auteurs;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add auteur
 *
 * @param \tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Auteur $auteur
 * @return Soumission
 */
 public function addAuteur(Auteur $auteur)
 {
    if ( ! $this->auteurs->contains($auteur) ) {
        $auteur->setSoumission($this);   // this should set the "soumission-
                                            id" field 
        $this->auteurs->add($auteur);
    }
    return $this->auteurs;
  }
   public function removeAuteur(Auteur $auteur)
    {
    if ($this->auteurs->contains($auteur)) {
        $this->auteurs->removeElement($auteur);
    }
    return $this->auteurs;
    }
   /**
 * @return mixed
 */
  public function getAuteurs()
  {
    return $this->auteurs;
    }
```

This is the auteur entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Soumission", inversedBy="auteur")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="soumission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $Soumission;
 /**
 * @param $soumission
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSoumission(Soumission $soumission)
{
    $this->soumission = $soumission;
    return $this;}
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSoumission()
{
    return $this->soumission;
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->Soumission;
}
```

[the result should be like the second line and not null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi29P.png)

Comment: the two entity are in the same bundle ?

Comment: you have some error in the mapping

Comment: Yes the two entity are in the same bundle

Comment: I can't figure out where are the mapping errors

Comment: inversedBy="auteurs" and not inversedBy="auteur" , soumission and not Soumission ..

Comment: nothing changed 
i always get "null"

Answer (score -2):

try to do this :

```
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Auteur",mappedBy="soumission", cascade={"persist"})
   */
   protected $auteurs;
/**
 * Add auteurs
 * @return FormationMsk
 */
public function addAuteur(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Auteur $auteurs)
{
    $this->auteurs[] = $auteurs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove auteurs
 */
public function removeAuteur(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Auteur $auteurs)
{
    $this->auteurs->removeElement($auteurs);
}

/**
 * Get auteurs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getAuteurs()
{
    return $this->auteurs;
}

 public function __construct()
{

    $this-auteurs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

  }
```

and for the auteur entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Soumission", inversedBy="auteurs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="soumission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $soumission;
```